# Separate multiple categorized tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a lot of test cases, and they should work different, depending on their category.
Example:

```
[Test]
[Category("Category1")
[Category("Category2")
private void DoSomething1()
{
    if(((System.Collections.ArrayList)
        TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["_CATEGORIES"]).Contains("Category2")
    {
        //Doing something specific by Category2
    }

    if(((System.Collections.ArrayList)
        TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["_CATEGORIES"]).Contains("Category1")
    {
        //Doing something specific by Category1
    }            
}
```

The problem is that when I start the test process from NUnit by picking Category2, then DoSomething1 should run only the Category2 specific case. Code duplication is not an option.

How could I do that?

Comment: You can't. The only way to do that, it's separate them in two methods.

Comment: @Chase Are you totally sure?

Comment: Yes, BTW, in ideology of Unit Tests you will take wrong way, if continue to do it as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me as if you should be running this as two or more different tests, just as @Chase mentions in a comment.

When I look at your test as written in your question, it immediately strikes me that this seems to complicated / unclear. You seem to be trying to work against how NUnit and unit testing in general works, and is intended to work.

In my experience, a good unit test is one where I almost don't need to think at all to understand what it does. The above example may not be very complicated in itself, but it seems *unusual* to do things this way, and it may confuse future readers, which is something you really want to avoid in a unit test; since it's purpose is to verify the correctness of your main code, the test itself should be as simple as possible in order to reduce any chance of errors in the test to an absolute minimum.

From your code, it looks as if it would be logical to simply duplicate your test, and use two separate, by similar tests instead.

---

PS: If you *absolutely do* want to use common logic for several tests, there are options like the following, which should limit what NUnit runs - but it's hard to see from your limited example whether or not this would make sense in your particular case:

```
[Test]
[Category("Category1")
private void DoSomethingForCat1()
{
    TestSomeStuff("category1");
}

[Test]
[Category("Category2")
private void DoSomethingForCat2()
{
    TestSomeStuff("category2");
}


private void TestSomeStuff(string category)
{
    if(category == "Category1"){
        (...)
    }
    else if(category == "Category2"){
        (...)
    }
}
```

Again, though this should be possible, I would not recommend it; it seems unusual and not very clean. You should definitely think about which solution will make your tests most clear when you decide what to do.